# In mysql how do I find rows repeating with respect to all fields?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

```
+------------+------------+
| student    | department |
+------------+------------+
| 1234567890 | CS         | 
| 1234567890 | ME         | 
| 1234567890 | CS         | 
| 000000001  | ME         | 
+------------+------------+
```

How can I get rows that are repeating with respect to both fields?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT student, department, count(*) as 'count' 
FROM students
GROUP BY student, department
HAVING count > 1
```

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| student    | department | count |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1234567890 | CS         | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be something like

```
SELECT  student,
    department      
FROM    Table
GROUP BY student, department
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY student, department
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1;
```